# Flink in Scala: Problem with map when trying to apply it to a DataStreamSource

Tags: json, scala, apache-flink

In my Scala code using Flink, I have been able to read from a Kafka topic like that:

```
val stream_demographic = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("topic_demographic",
    new SimpleStringSchema(), properties_demographic))
```

The stream_demographic val is of type DataStreamSource. However, when I try to apply map to it for parsing the JSON that is being received, I get an error:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Y0p.png)

It leads to "Cannot resolve overloaded method 'map'", so I'm not able to parse anything since it is an error. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the official documentation, I could identify the problem: I was loading bad dependencies for scala api of Flink.

Comment: What were the exact bad dependencies?